# Should civicrm_post hook receive populated Relationship object following relationship enable/disable in UI?

Tags: hooks, relationships

I'm porting some code using Civi hooks from Civi 4.4 to 4.6 . The code needs to know when a relationship becomes active or inactive, regardless of how that happens, including via the enable/disable links on the Relationships tab.

My implementation for 4.4 used both hook_civicrm_post and hook_civicrm_enableDisable. In Civi 4.6, [hook_civicrm_enableDisable has been removed](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=124813469). I've found that hook_civicrm_post gets called when the enable/disable links are used but the CRM_Contact_DAO_Relationship object passed in only has the id field populated, all the other fields are blank.

Is this a bug and so should be addressed in core, or intended behaviour and so something I have to work around in my hook implementation?

I'm using CiviCRM 4.6.4 with Drupal 7.

Comment: I've run into this before: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15914

Answer (score 2):

Sorry but it's the intended behavior. Generally pre and post hooks just pass whatever happens to be loaded in that object rather than taking the performance hit of doing a full database load for the sake of a hook which may or may not be implemented and may or may not care.

I recommend not relying on the object being passed to pre/post hooks and doing your own api lookup using the provided id.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, Coleman. I think this is the first case I've come across of a post hook not receiving a populated object for op = 'edit'. However hook_civicrm_enableDisable wasn't receiving one, so in that sense I'm no worse off. Better be extra-careful with post hooks now though.