# constraint violation during event registration

Tags: civievent

Getting constraint violation error during event registration. I found that, this error happening when it's saving the custom field value after saving participant info. There is a post hook in my custom module, in that i have code(**civicrm_api("Relationship", "create",$params)**) to create relationship for contact, if i comment that line it's working fine.
Current version am using is CiviCRM 4.6.2. This issue was not there with my previous version 4.3.5.

Can we not use create-api in post hook?

Please suggest.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the actual code snippet that you believe is causing the error, as well as the full error message itself.

Comment: I have pasted the code as multiple comment since it's not allowing to past all code at once,

#0 D:\wamp\www\mysite\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Core\Error.php(182): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace()
#1 [internal function](): CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(DB_Error))
#2 D:\wamp\www\mysite\sites\all\modules\civicrm\packages\PEAR.php(931): call_user_func((Array:2), Object(DB_Error))
#3 D:\wamp\www\mysite\sites\all\modules\civicrm\packages\DB.php(976): PEAR_Error->PEAR_Error("DB Error: constraint violation", -3, 16, (Array:2), "INSERT INTO civicrm_value_health_information_55  ( please_list_any_p...")

Comment: #4 D:\wamp\www\mysite\sites\all\modules\civicrm\packages\PEAR.php(564): DB_Error->DB_Error(-3, 16, (Array:2), "INSERT INTO civicrm_value_health_information_55  ( please_list_any_p...")
#5 D:\wamp\www\mysite\sites\all\modules\civicrm\packages\DB\common.php(1905): PEAR->raiseError(NULL, -3, NULL, NULL, "INSERT INTO civicrm_value_health_information_55  ( please_list_any_p...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#6 D:\wamp\www\mysite\sites\all\modules\civicrm\packages\DB\mysql.php(899): DB_common->raiseError(-3, NULL, NULL, NULL, "1452 ** Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ha...")

Comment: #7 D:\wamp\www\mysite\sites\all\modules\civicrm\packages\DB\mysql.php(328): DB_mysql->mysqlRaiseError()

#8 D:\wamp\www\mysite\sites\all\modules\civicrm\packages\DB\common.php(1216): DB_mysql->simpleQuery("INSERT IN

#9 D:\wamp\www\mysite\sites\all\modules\civicrm\packages\DB\DataObject.php(2442): DB_common->query("INSERT INTO civicrm_value_health_information_55  ( please_list_any_p...")

Comment: #10 D:\wamp\www\mysite\sites\all\modules\civicrm\packages\DB\DataObject.php(1634): DB_DataObject->_query("INSERT INTO civicrm_value_health_information_55  ( please_list_any_p...")
#11 D:\wamp\www\mysite\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Core\DAO.php(325): DB_DataObject->query("INSERT INTO civicrm_value_health_information_55  ( please_list_any_p...")
#12 D:\wamp\www\mysite\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Core\DAO.php(1179): CRM_Core_DAO->query("INSERT INTO civicrm_value_health_information_55  ( please_list_any_p...", TRUE)

Comment: #13 D:\wamp\www\mysite\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Core\BAO\CustomValueTable.php(241): CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery("INSERT INTO civicrm_value_health_information_55  ( please_list_any_p...", (Array:4))
#14 D:\wamp\www\mysite\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Core\BAO\CustomValueTable.php(349): CRM_Core_BAO_CustomValueTable::create((Array:3))
#15 D:\wamp\www\mysite\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Core\BAO\CustomValueTable.php(370): CRM_Core_BAO_CustomValueTable::store((Array:34), "civicrm_participant", 5148)

Comment: #17 D:\wamp\www\mysite\sites\all\modules\my_custom\civicrm\CRM\Event\Form\Registration\Confirm.php(1015): CRM_Event_Form_Registration->confirmPostProcess("1", Object(CRM_Contribute_BAO_Contribution), Object(CRM_Core_Payment_PayPalImpl))
#18 D:\wamp\www\mysite\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Core\Form.php(345): CRM_Event_Form_Registration_Confirm->postProcess()

Comment: #19 D:\wamp\www\mysite\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Core\StateMachine.php(164): CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess()
#20 D:\wamp\www\mysite\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Core\QuickForm\Action\Next.php(61): CRM_Core_StateMachine->perform(Object(CRM_Event_Form_Registration_Confirm), "next", "Next")
#21 D:\wamp\www\mysite\sites\all\modules\civicrm\packages\HTML\QuickForm\Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Next->perform(Object(CRM_Event_Form_Registration_Confirm), "next")

Comment: #22 D:\wamp\www\mysite\sites\all\modules\civicrm\packages\HTML\QuickForm\Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Event_Form_Registration_Confirm), "next")
#23 D:\wamp\www\mysite\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Core\Controller.php(353): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("next")
#24 D:\wamp\www\mysite\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Core\Invoke.php(312): CRM_Core_Controller->run((Array:3), NULL)
#25 D:\wamp\www\mysite\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Core\Invoke.php(86): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:15))

Comment: **Code in post_hook,**

function customlogic_civicrm_post($op, $objectName, $id, &$params) {
    if ('Participant' == $objectName) {
  $r = civicrm_api("Relationship", "create", array(version => '3', 'sequential' => '1', 'contact_id_a' => $contact_id_1, 'contact_id_b' => $contact_id_2, 'relationship_type_id' => 12));
 }
}

Comment: Additional details go in the question, not as comments. Please move the comments into your question, formatted as code. It's currently not very readable in this format.

Answer (score 1):

If your hook relies on $objectRef being populated, check whether it actually is - they aren't always. See [Should civicrm_post hook receive populated Relationship object following relationship enable/disable in UI?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3901/should-civicrm-post-hook-receive-populated-relationship-object-following-relatio)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to do some debugging as to why it is happening. If you turn back-trace & debugging on (debugging is an option under administer/system settings) you should be able to see the failing query and the backtrace. If you can't interpret them you should paste them back here